# Is there a way to re-order the Custom Taxonomy drop-down on a Custom Post listing page?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, register-taxonomy

I have used `register_taxonomy()` with `'show_admin_column' => true` successfully to get a drop-down on my custom post type listing page. The drop-down displays the terms in ID order by default.

Anyone know a way to change this to Alpha order?

Comment: `'show_admin_column' => true` can not add the drop-down by itself. It adds only a column to the List Table. What code did you use to create the drop-down?

Answer (score 0):

@Max - good call! Did some more digging and found a wp_dropdown_categories embedded in a function where I could use 'orderby'.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is facing the same problem, here is the snippet:

```
// Based on the User Contributed Notes of the Codex
add_action('restrict_manage_posts','my_post_type_filter', 10, 2);

function my_post_type_filter($post_type, $which){
    if('faq' !== $post_type){
        return; // check the post type
    }
    $taxonomy_slug = 'faq_cat';  // subject to change
    $taxonomy = get_taxonomy($taxonomy_slug);
    $request_attr = 'faq_cat'; // subject to change, will show up in the url
    $selected = '';
    if ( isset($_REQUEST[$request_attr] ) ) {
        $selected = $_REQUEST[$request_attr]; // in case the current page is already filtered
    }

    wp_dropdown_categories(array(
        'show_option_all' =>  __("Show All {$taxonomy->label}"),
        'taxonomy'        =>  $taxonomy_slug,
        'name'            =>  $request_attr,
        'orderby'         =>  'name',
        'order'           =>  'ASC',
        'hierarchical'    =>  true,
        'depth'           =>  1,
        'show_count'      =>  true, // Show number of post in parent term
        'hide_empty'      =>  false, // Don't show posts w/o terms
        'selected'        =>  $selected,
    ));
  }

/**
 * Filter posts by taxonomy in admin
 * @author  Mike Hemberger
 * @link http://thestizmedia.com/custom-post-type-filter-admin-custom-taxonomy/
 */
add_filter('parse_query', 'tsm_convert_id_to_term_in_query');

function tsm_convert_id_to_term_in_query($query) {
    global $pagenow;
    $post_type = 'faq'; // subject to change
    $taxonomy  = 'faq_cat'; // subject to change
    $q_vars    = &$query->query_vars;
    if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && isset($q_vars['post_type']) && $q_vars['post_type'] == $post_type && isset($q_vars[$taxonomy]) && is_numeric($q_vars[$taxonomy]) && $q_vars[$taxonomy] != 0 ) {
        $term = get_term_by('id', $q_vars[$taxonomy], $taxonomy);
        $q_vars[$taxonomy] = $term->slug;
    }
}
```